# Where do I get token API?

Tags: api, blockchain

Now I'm calling some usdt data.

I want historical data related to usdt, such as name, symbol, circulation amount, transfer and other information. What api can I use？

I would like to get some information about the usdt api

Comment: A well-formed question will include what you've tried and what the result was.

Answer (score 1):

I know tokenview.io have an API service, can provide the information.

For example, we can call this api to get some basic information:
[https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/{lowercase-coin-abbr}/token/{token-address}?apikey={apikey}](https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/%7Blowercase-coin-abbr%7D/token/%7Btoken-address%7D?apikey=%7Bapikey%7D)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZV3u.png)

Call this interface to get a list of token transactions:
[https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/{lowercase-coin-abbr}/token/tokentrans/{token-address}/{page}/{page-size}?apikey={apikey}](https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/%7Blowercase-coin-abbr%7D/token/tokentrans/%7Btoken-address%7D/%7Bpage%7D/%7Bpage-size%7D?apikey=%7Bapikey%7D)

More detailed data you can directly open the website: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/5728777/SVSEvX8k?version=latest